# XPath : Bind to last item of collection

Tags: wpf, binding

Can I `Bind` `TextBox.Text` to last item of an `ObservableCollection<string>` ?

I tried this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding XPath="Model/CollectionOfString[last()]"/>
```

But it doesn't bind.

Thank you.

Comment: here is another way to do it. [Binding a button in a list view to the last item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720553/only-enable-the-last-remove-element-button-of-a-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the method following,

1, use IValueConverter.

```
class DataSourceToLastItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> items = value as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (items != null)
        {
            return items.LastOrDefault();
        }
        else return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then binding like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DataSourceToLastItemConverter x:Key="DataSourceToLastItemConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model.CollectionOfString,Converter={StaticResource DataSourceToLastItemConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You mean where is no way to do it using `XPath`?

Comment: :I need `TwoWay` Can I `ConvertBack`?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way using XPaht, but I'm sure you can implement the ConvertBack method to do the two way binding. Just remember adding twoway binding in the XAML :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't bind because you cannot use the [`XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx) property on a-non XML data source; you have to use [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) instead, and that property doesn't offer similar syntax. So you cannot directly bind to the last element of the collection unless you know the index of the last value. However there are a couple workarounds available:

#### Bind using a value converter

It's not difficult to write custom [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that takes the collection and "converts" it to its last element. [Howard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779170/50079) gives a barebones converter that does this.

#### Bind to the current item in the collection view

This is even easier to do, but it involves code-behind.

You can bind using `Path=Model.CollectionOfString/` (note the slash at the end) if you have set the "current" item in the default [collection view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#collection_views) to be the last item in the collection. Do this inside your model:

```
// get a reference to the default collection view for this.CollectionOfString
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefault(this.CollectionOfString);

// set the "current" item to the last, enabling direct binding to it with a /
collectionView.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

Be aware that if items are added to or removed from the collection, the current item pointer will not necessarily be adjusted automatically.

Comment: But I don't like to have `CollectionView` in my domain model

Comment: @Mohsen: Depending on how your code is structured, you could do the same from within your view. Otherwise you can always wrap the model inside a viewmodel, MVVM-style.